Proof of Lemma 6.3 in Jech's Set Theory
From page 64 in Jech's Set Theory:

Lemma 6.3. For every $x$ there is an $\alpha$ such that $x \in V_\alpha$:
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}} V_\alpha = V.
$$
Proof. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of all $x$ that are not in any $V_\alpha$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is nonempty, then $\mathcal{C}$ has an $\in$-minimal element $x$. That is, $x \in \mathcal{C}$, and $z \in \bigcup_{\alpha} V_\alpha$ for every $z \in x$. Hence $x \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}} V_\alpha$. By Replacement, there exists an ordinal $\gamma$ such that $x \subset \bigcup_{\alpha < \gamma} V_\alpha$. Hence $x \subset V_\gamma$ and so $x \in V_{\gamma+1}$. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is empty and we have the result.

How does Replacement imply the existence of the ordinal $\gamma$?

For each $z\in x$, let $\alpha_z$ be the least ordinal such that $z\in V_{\alpha_z}$ (and let $\alpha_z = 0$ for $z\notin x$).  Then $F(z) = \alpha_z$ is a definable function, so by Replacement there is a set $F[x] = \{\alpha_z\mid z\in x\}$. Let $\gamma = \sup\{\alpha_z\mid z\in x\}+1$. Then for each $z\in x$, $z\in V_{\alpha_z}$ and $\alpha_z<\gamma$, so $x\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}V_\alpha$.
I'll note that this is a bog standard application of Replacement. We want to show there is an ordinal $\gamma$ large enough to satisfy some property $P$ (in our case, $P$ is $x\subseteq V_\gamma$). We break $P$ down into a set of conditions (in our case, the conditions $z\in V_\gamma$ for each $z\in x$), each of which is satisfied by some ordinal $\alpha_z$. By Replacement, the witnesses $\alpha_z$ form a set. Now one of the most basic facts about ordinals is that every set of ordinals has a supremum, which is our $\gamma$. Many many arguments involving the ordinals go exactly like this.
